# Best protocol for daisy chain communication between many small microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, communication, digital-communications, protocol

I'm working on a project where I'd like a large number of small microcontrollers (100+, something like an 8-bit PIC, but flexible on what I use) to each perform audio synthesis behavior defined by an 1-4 byte shift register. The idea is to program each micro as an oscillator and have frequency, pulse width, and phase each controlled by the register data and to have one master device pass data to all the smaller devices in a daisy chain configuration.

Think of it as the audio equivalent of a WS LED strip.

For this to work properly, I need a protocol that can spit out high-speed data to all the micros, allow each micro in the chain to pass data on to the next micro as it is being clocked in, and then update each micro simultaneously once the data write is complete.

It also needs to be a protocol that can survive going some distance over a wire run, I will almost certainly add an input / output buffer to the PCBs, but assume wire runs between PCBs can be up to 10 ft.

What am I looking for to do this properly based on the parameters I have described?

Comment: this may help ... https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vjc4ZF5own8

Comment: Are you looking for a physical daisychain, i.e. where each talks to the next (and none other), or do you mean that all are connected in parallel ("multi-drop")?

Comment: physical daisy chain

Comment: Ethercat if you can afford it. Canopen if good enough. Modbus could work too

Comment: @TQQQ - Thanks for trying to help, but [answers shouldn't be put into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Please consider moving that into an answer.

Comment: @SamGibson yes, but the standard of answers is such that I can't do it this time. Sorry.

Comment: Since nobody mentioned it yet, CAN bus is pretty good for this

Comment: You bring up the WS strip but don't explain why you wouldn't use the same signalling/protocol. Doesn't that solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

That's literally what SPI is: clocking bits into the shift register in each microcontroller, while clocking out the ones already stored in there.

Since any reasonable MCU already has an SPI peripheral, there's nothing you need to invent.

Distance here is mostly a matter of speed, and you can be as slow as your application allows. ("High-speed" sadly tells me nothing? Is this an easy 1 Mbd, or a hard 50 MBd? Who knows.) Should you need higher speed, the standard way is just to add a differential line driver at each MCU's output, and to just buffer the differential bit clock, as well.

8 bit PICs are currently overly expensive for their capabilities, so you'd probably fare cheaper with an stm32c0 or similar. Also makes the audio stuff much easier, as you get far far far superior timer/PWM units. Plus, programming equipment for cortex-m0 MCUs like these is much cheaper, and the compilers much better, so that this would really be a no-brainer for me.

Comment: SPI with a return clock?

Comment: For example, or even with return Data, which helps if you don't know the strong length beforehand

Comment: Just don't make OPs project unnecessary expensive because of fanboyism. A PIC is still cheaper and perfectly fine for the purpose with its hardware SPI and PWM. It doesn't matter if the stm is 100 times faster but only 50% more expensive.

Comment: @pipe At least from my distibutors the STM is actually cheaper, esp if we only consider PICs with enough RAM to work on a decent window length. AVRs fall somewhere between those two.

Comment: Is there a way to configure a SPI peripheral to automatically write out the data it receives in after a certain number of bits are filled in the configurations I described? Would this involve connecting MOSI to MISO on the next micro in the chain, but keeping the clock and chip select lines connected to the main controller board?

Comment: @RobertMartinu Window length for what? It's going to beep a square wave at different frequencies.

Comment: @pipe I must admit I just checked digikey for MCUs with at least 1 kB of RAM and saw an stm32c0 for 64 ct, and was basically surprised how expensive the comparable PIC became! I will straight up admit that I prefer arm over PIC any day from a programmer's perspective, and I'll also admit my fantasy regarding things that one could build with a MCU with multiple timers with dma units ran a bit wild (you can actually chirp, add timbre, if you want, you could even DDS the pwm unit and become much more sinudoidal!), but far am I from fanboying cortex-m0 in 2024. That architecture is kind of

Comment: obsolete itself, isn't it, and ST rather continuing to pay royalties to arm than invest in porting their USP peripheral set to a line of modern cores (like risc-v, there's multiple known implementations that are smaller than a cortex-m0 yet as capable) is a whole palette of sad.

Comment: @EmmettPalaima essentially, yes; you'd just use the DMA engine to write what it receives to a specific memory location, but configure the peripheral to only do that when the chip select line is asserted.

Comment: @pipe The cheap and small AVRs have less bytes RAM then some of the common UARTs use for oversampling. If you want to decode long/short beeps with a somewhat flexible frequency and perhaps even tolerance for signal glitches that's  a lot of effort for no gain.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a job for DMX512. DMX512 uses RS-485 with simple serial coding, well within the reach of an 8-bit micro (some Microchip devices even have DMX hardware support, see below.)

Up to 512 8-bit DMX nodes per ‘universe’ are supported, at a refresh rate of 44Hz. Data is sent as entire frames at fixed time intervals.

DMX can physically support up to 32 devices in a daisy chain. Stage setups will often break up DMX into several branches using repeaters, or even break them out as separate universes if a higher refresh rate is needed.

DMX512 devices are electrically daisy-chained using twisted-pair 'balanced' audio cables terminated with XLR plugs. Termination is 120 ohms.

Some DMX implementers will use CAT3 type twisted pair cable instead of audio cables. You could choose that and save the cost.

Finally, there are wireless and Ethernet bridging options for DMX512.

More about DMX512 [here, from Microchip](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-19E32404-10A3-4F82-A4B0-9332290B918C-en-US-1/index.html).

Comment: I also immediately thought of DMX-512, but decided to not suggest it because on second thought it is a poor fit. As it defines the connectors, cabling,electrical interface and isolation, it is too clunky to implement as-is. Each MCU requires UART and RS485 receiver(transceiver), and address configuration, isolated interface, and for 100+ MCUs, you need 200+ XLR plugs and 200+ XLR sockets, and while there are RS485 PHY chips capable of 200+ PHYs on bus, DMX-512 limits that to the original RS-485 max of 32 devices or less if fail-safe biasing and repeaters are used. Similar protocol should work.

Comment: I mean I could easily use the DMX serial format with different connectors. I think buffering is something I'll have to figure out regardless of what format I use, since sending data signals over long cable runs can make that tricky. 

My main question here would be how to synchronize the DMX register loads such that all the boards update at the same time, which is a requirement for me

Comment: DMX syncs after you've sent the entire payload, so this will ensure the update is coordinated.

Comment: Also, DMX over RJ45 is common, especially when used for fixed setups. Stage users prefer XLR due to its toughness and serviceability.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a project like this and ended up using the RP2040 with two RS-485 ICs, one for "upstream" messages toward the controller and one for "downstream" messages, using both RP2040 UART buses. Then, when the final boards were in sequence, they all communicated by incrementing the ID in a JSON message. This allowed the firmware on each board to be identical with no dipswitches or other addressing requirements, and the RS-485 protocol allowed for a highly variable distance between each board.

In the final version, broadcasts could be sent from the controller to all boards, or messages could be targeted to any individual board in the array.